# No module named xlsxwriter.workbook -Ironpython

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, ironpython

I was trying to call a python code using C# ironpython. But encountering this error.

"No module named xlsxwriter.workbook"

Getting this error on import line only.

While the same code is running in that machine with regular python(version 2.7)

Please help.

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening probably because the xmlwriter library you are referring to is installed in the Python 2.7 interpreter, but not in the IronPython distribution.

You would have to download the xmlwriter package, extract it to a folder and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

using the IronPython executable - as shown in https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/index.html.

Hope this helps!